# TextInput allow font scaling false

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I'm building an app with React Native. The problem is that, when the font size is changed through the phone's settings, the font sizes also change in the app, even though they're all set a fixed font size.

For example, consider the following `Text` element with font size 12:

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 12}}>Hello World</Text>
```

I've found out that there's a prop named `allowFontScaling` for this issue.So, I go to `App.js` and add the following line for disabling the font scaling throughout the app:

```
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

It works perfectly. However, the same prop doesn't seem be not implemented for `TextInput` element. When I try doing the same for `TextInput`, I get the following error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_reactNative.TextInput.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false')

Therefore, I may set a fixed font size for `Text`, but not `TextInput`. Is there any workaround for this issue? My react-native version is 0.48.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `<TextInput allowFontScaling={false}>` on a `TextInput` and see if it works on that specific `TextInput`? Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/textinput.html#allowfontscaling

Comment: @IshitaSinha I think he is trying to avoid having to add it to 500 text components all over his app

Comment: @A.com obviously. Checking whether adding it individually works or not was just a means of debugging where the problem lies. According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#allowfontscaling) `allowFontScaling` is a valid TextInput prop, so it should work. If it did, I would ask him to do it this way: `TextInput.defaultProps = {
  allowFontScaling: false
};`

Comment: `TextInput.defaultProps = { allowFontScaling: false };` worked like a charm for me.

Comment: `TextInput.defaultProps = { ...(TextInput.defaultProps || {}), allowFontScaling: false }` from here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18827#issuecomment-407854026

Answer (score 5):

An easy solution to solve this is to add the following code on top of my App.js file:

```js
Text.defaultProps = {
  ...(Text.defaultProps || {}),
  allowFontScaling: false,
};
TextInput.defaultProps = {
  ...(TextInput.defaultProps || {}),
  allowFontScaling: false,
};
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, it's working nice on RN 0.64

Answer (score 2):

As allowFontScaling prop of "TextInput" does not work on android the workaround for both iOS and android is to -

1. import PixelRatio from react-native
2. In TextInput style set your fontSize to {intendedFontSize / PixelRatio.getFontScale()}

It will fix your fontSize and won't change because of system settings

Answer (score 2):

You can add this code in your app.js file. This is the valid way to use in .jsx file instead .ts

```
useEffect(() => {
    Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
    Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
    TextInput.defaultProps = TextInput.defaultProps || {};
    TextInput.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
    View.defaultProps = View.defaultProps || {};
    View.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
  }, [])
```